# Is there a way to make this CSS animation less clunky without relying on JavaScript?

Tags: css, css-animations

So, I am attempting to animate image tiles on this page to appear/disappear and grow/shrink depending on their class (which is changed by selecting a category from the top menu). The way that the animation works currently has most of the idea there, but there seems to be a lot of clunkiness to it - especially going from the "Show All" screen to any of the sections with fewer tiles.

I'd like to avoid using javascript for any of the animation other than appending a CSS class depending on which tiles are being shown/hidden.

Is there a way to actually make the look of transform: scale(); work with moving the tiles around as opposed to resorting to the use of changing the height/width of the tiles which makes them resize from the top/left?

The demo version of the animation is available here: https://wolfandthunder.com/demo/israel_arias/v2/

Comment: Can you post the code or make a [runnable example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do)?

Comment: Sidenote: are these 'pages' going to have URLs? because if they aren't - it's a major bummer for the client.

Comment: It's more complex than the CSS - it's about the timing of the sort. This is the type of thing that https://isotope.metafizzy.co/ really takes care of smoothly. I think you can handle the animation with CSS / but not everything else that you'd need to be able to get that in place to work. Good luck.

Comment: @sheriffderek what do you mean by "the timing of the sort"? The category sorting is already handled by javascript just fine I believe, are you referring to something else?

Comment: @sheriffderek it looks like this isotope example is directly editing inline styling with JavaScript - which is not what I'd like to do. Is it possible to do this same thing by just adding a class name to the element?

Comment: @sheriffderek it could be URL based - though that is up to the client. It may or may no make sense depending on how these tiles are actually incorporated into the overall website.